# python 2 to 3 migration error "readinto" method

Tags: python

I converted a huge file which I wrote it at python 2.7.3 and then now I wanted to upgrade to python 3+ (i have 3.5).

1. what I have done so far:

   1. installed the python interpreter 3.5+
   2. updated the environment path to read from python3+ folder
   3. upgraded the numpy, pandas,
   4. I used `>python 2to3.py -w viterbi.py` to convert to version 3+

the section that I have error

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Counting number of lines in the text file
lines = 0
buffer = bytearray(2048)
with open(inputFilePatheName) as f:
    while f.readinto(buffer) > 0:
        lines += buffer.count('\n')
```

My error is:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'readinto'
```

This is the first error and I cannot proceed to see if there is any other error. I dont know what is the equivalent command for `readinto`

Comment: have you tried `with open(inputFilePatheName, 'rb') as f:` ?

Comment: I did now it says  ` lines += buffer.count('\n')`   `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ` . my input file is a text file/

Comment: Have you tried ``'rt'`` or just ``'r'`` instead of ``'rb'`` mode?

Comment: thanks, there are many things that i have to change therefore, i think its better to rewrite the codes in py3

Comment: As far as I can tell from my searching, this shouldn't have worked in 2.x, either. At least, the `buffer.count` would work, but `.readinto` should still have required a file open in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file as binary.

As long as you can guarantee it's `utf-8` or CP encoded, all `\n`s will necessarily be newlines:

```
with open(inputFilePatheName, "rb") as f:
    while f.readinto(buffer) > 0:
        lines += buffer.count(b'\n')
```

That way you also save the time of decoding the file, and use your buffer in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: "As long as you can guarantee it's utf-8 encoded, all \ns will neccesarily be newlines:" This makes little sense. Any ASCII-transparent encoding (i.e., UTF-8, ASCII itself, as well as anything calling itself a "code page" or similar) will treat `b'\n'` as a Unicode `'\n'`. On the flip side, a new line in a text file might be represented by the `'\r'` code point instead, and Unicode encoding will have nothing to do with it. It could also be represented by one of each. Please see the section in the documentation about universal newline handling for files in text mode.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel regarding the `\r`, I agree, specifically in old macs it would be an issue, but nowadays it is practically non-existent AFAIK. About my comment for `utf-8`, `0x0a` can be in the middle of a `UTF-16` or `UTF-32`, as they don't have the MSB set IIRC, and as UTF-16 is the default encoding for most things on Windows, I find it as a possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x, the [`readinto` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readinto#io.RawIOBase.readinto) is only available on binary I/O streams. Thus: `with open(inputFilePatheName, 'rb') as f:`.

Separately, `buffer.count('\n')` will not work any more, because Python 3.x handles text properly, as something distinct from a raw sequence of bytes. `buffer`, being a `bytearray`, stores bytes; it still has a `.count` method, but it has to be given either an integer (representing the numeric value of a byte to look for) or a "bytes-like object" (representing a subsequence of bytes to look for). So we also have to update that, as `buffer.count(b'\n')` (using a `bytes` literal).

Finally, we need to be aware that processing the file this way means we [don't get universal newline translation by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) any more.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to what you're trying to achieve is using memory mapped files.

In case of Windows:

```
file_handle = os.open(r"yourpath", os.O_RDONLY|os.O_BINARY|os.O_SEQUENTIAL)
try:
  with mmap.mmap(file_handle, 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as f:
    pos = -1
    total = 0
    while (pos := f.find(b"\n", pos+1)) != -1:
      total +=1
finally:
  os.close(file_handle)
```

Again, make sure you are not encoding the text as `UTF-16` which is the default for Windows.

Comment: That seems a bit heavy-handed for a question that was specifically about migrating a codebase from 2.x to 3.x, no?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not sure to be honest. Per the comments section, he eventually wished to rewrite the code in Python 3,  and I have a feeling this solution will be more efficient. It probably depends on the ratio of `\n` to other bytes in the file. Might as well include it for completeness :-)